# Instagram Permission review declined due to Instagram brand name - App name violates Instagram brand name guidelines

Tags: windows, permissions, instagram, instagram-api, review

I am developing a windows application which uses Instagram's api with public scope, I had sent my app for review but it was declined by Instagram saying "Your App uses Instagram Brand name in such a way that isn't permitted". My application name starts with **InstaXXXX** So does any one has any idea what would be the exact problem because there are lot of applications in market whose name contains the word **Insta**,Or is there any other issue, Please answer to my question and help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your application name should not contain anything with the words 
**"Insta"** or **"gram"** or anything similar.

we are trying to get Instagram approval's for 3 months(for all API except basic), but Instagram rejected us.
they are rejected because of invalid use cases. I searched in google and understand they are rejecting plenty of clients.

I hope they approve your submission.